# Get AWS::StackName without the generated random hash

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How can one get the AWS::StackName without the random generate part?

I create a stack: `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name test`

The stack name returned when evaluated using `AWS:StackName` will included a random generated part, e.g. `test-KB0IKRIHP9PH`

What I really want returned is the parameter without the generated part, in this case `test`,
omitting `-KB0IKRIHP9PH`

---

My use case for this is, when my containers startup, they need to get database
credential from a pre created named secret. With the random part in place the service all fail to start initially until the secrets are created.

In the code below I assign the StackName to an environment variable.

```
TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: website-service
          Environment:
            - Name: ENVIRONMENT_VAR
              Value: !Join ["", ["CF_", {"Ref": "AWS::StackName"}]]
```

---

Here is an update as requested, to show how I create the stack. I am using a MakeFile...

```
create-test: s3
    @ip_address=$$(dig @resolver1.opendns.com ANY myip.opendns.com     +short); \
    read -s -p "Enter DB Root Password: "  pswd; \
    [[ -z $$pswd ]] && exit 1 || \
    aws cloudformation create-stack \
    --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM \
    --stack-name test \
    --template-body file://master.yaml \
    --parameters ParameterKey=DBRootPassword,ParameterValue=$$pswd \
    ParameterKey=DBHostAccessCidr,ParameterValue=$$ip_address/32
```

Comment: Hi. Can you provide example of how you create a stack. `--stack-name` is the name of the stack. Normally there are no random characters there. Do you run the command manually, or through some deployment tool? Maybe the tool adds that random bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nested Stack Names** contain a random hash.

To overcome the problem, pass the `AWS::StackName` as a parameter to the nested stack, from the root/master stack.

---

In the example below, the `AWS::StackName` is passed as a parameter.

**master.yaml**

```
Resources:
  S3:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/...s3.yaml
      Parameters:
        ParamStackName: !Ref AWS::StackName
```

---

**s3.yaml** Notice: `!Ref AWS::StackName` while **nested**, will include a random hash.

```
 Parameters:
    ParamStackName:
      Type: String
 
 Resources:
    MyS3:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        # Using !Ref AWS::StackName will include the random hash
        BucketName: !Ref ParamStackName
```

Answer (score 4):

I test this with a simple template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:

  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

Outputs:
  
  Stack:
    Value: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}
```

The **Stack** output variable exactly matched the name of the stack that I created. There were *no* random characters.

I launched the stack via the console.

Comment: Stack names need to be unique, and when used with nested stacks, CloudFormation appends the stack name with a random hash. See my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

If `AWS::StackName` is in the form of `test-KB0IKRIHP9PH`, then you can get `test` and perform the Join as follows:

```
Environment:
  - Name: ENVIRONMENT_VAR
    Value: !Join ["", ["CD_", !Select [0, !Split ['-', !Ref "AWS::StackName"] ] ] ]
```